# Loop to determine selectedIndex isn't working?

Tags: javascript, html, select, for-loop, selectedindex

My function `SelectBeatle` checks `input#FindBeatle` and sets the `selectedIndex` of `select#Beatles` to the value of `input#FindBeatle`

However, for some odd reason, it seems as though the my loop won't run:
http://jsfiddle.net/js_test/M9ty7/

Am I missing something?

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="FindBeatle" type="text" />

<select id="Beatles">
    <option>John</option>
    <option>Paul</option>
    <option>George</option>
    <option>Ringo</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="SelectBeatle()" value="Submit" />
```

and here is my JS:

```
var SelectBeatle = function(){
    var sel = document.getElementById('Beatles'),
        val = document.getElementById('FindBeatle').value;

        for(var i = 0, j = sel.options.length; i < j; i++) {
            if(sel.options[i].innerHTML === val) {
                sel.selectedIndex = i;
                break;
            }else{
                alert("Try Again!");
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` at this point of your code `txt = sel.options[i].innerHTML`?

Comment: Thanks @Xotic750 I've edited my question as well as my jsfiddle to reflect your recommendation. However, it still does not work.

Comment: Set `no wrap - in <body>` on your jsFiddle. The second pulldown option.

Comment: This is an example of why you should consider separating HTML, Javascript and CSS - [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), and you can read more about [events at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. @Xotic750 I found [A guide to writing unobtrusive JavaScript and Ajax](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-unobtrusive/) as well. I'll read everything tonight. I got the jsfiddle to work by removing `var` from my `SelectBeatle` function. Do you know anything about that quirk?

Comment: You have now made it a `global` rather than in the scope that was being executed on jsFiddle. Not a good solution IMO. Now when you copy your code to a real `js` file to load onto your server, be sure to put it back and use an `onload` event, otherwise be prepared for global pollution.

Comment: Here is some reading about [var on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) to give you some idea about scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the console said SelectBeatle is undefined... so your function is probably not visible in the html scope when you click the button.

When you say `var`, in js, that var only exists inside the current scope. JSFiddle adds a function wrapper in its javascript, limiting your scope.

Of course the best option is to capture the click event of the button:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');
btn.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    SelectBeatle();
});
```

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/M9ty7/15/

Comment: Updated answer to a cleaner solution

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it's an improvement on the original code and works in spite of jsfiddle's fickleness. Thanks for the heads up, I almost missed it.

Comment: I was revisiting your answer and had two quick questions:
**No.1 --** I noticed you replaced the the `sel.selectedIndex = i;` and `break;` in my conditional to `continue;`. Why is that? Am I right in assuming that `continue;` kicks you out of the loop, once it runs out of iterations, w/o executing the code at the end?

**No.2 --** Why is the `return` at the end? What is it `return`ing if there's nothing to `return`?

Comment: **No.1** Yes, it will break out of the loop and alert something is missing. **No.2** It will leave the function, as we found the index we wanted and therefore will not run the alert saying something is missing, because it isn't.

Comment: No.1 is definitely more sophisticated than the `break` method I was using. I'm glad to have learned it. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Your js is breaking when you set the initial `txt` value.

`txt = sel.options[i].innerHTML;`

`i` doesn't yet exist

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question as well as my jsfiddle to reflect your recommendation. However, it still does not work.

Comment: Works for me, you need to change how jsfiddle loads the script but the code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/M9ty7/11/

Comment: [in meta] I wish there was a way to accept answers as steps... seeing that this is step 1 to fix the code, and the accepted answer is step 2...

Answer (score 0):

Take out the var before your function definition. At least in jsfiddle, this is causing your function definition to not be available to your button click

Comment: That was it. Do you know what causes that quirk?

Comment: That's scope, when you say `var`, in js, that var only exists inside the current scope. JSFiddle adds a function wrapper in its javascript, limiting your scope.
Yet best option is to not use `onclick=""` at all, use jquery!

Comment: declaring a variable with var sets the scope to the current function. jsfiddle possibly runs your input JavaScript code from within its own function, so when the jsfiddle function finishes your input function goes out of scope. Edit: SparK beat me to it, also agree that jquery is better if you can use it.

Comment: Wilhelm take a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M9ty7/15/

@TheDark when both have the same answer it's probably right :P

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#FindBeatle').val($('#Beatles').val());
```

OR

```
$('#FindBeatle').val($('#Beatles :selected').text());
```